# sql managment studio is sending and receing data with no reason

Tags: traffic, ssms

I am programming and the sql management studio was left open I detected an unusual amount of data transfer by sql management studio (mostly sending out) it was continuously sending with speed of 16 KB/s and receiving with 6 KB/s.

If it was all download I would have thought that is an update but how about sending data when the program is not even being used. the total amount of send were 47 MB when I saw it.

is this indicating a problem? like being hacked? or is it normal? if it is normal what is the reason?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any add-ins installed ? Some add-ins check for new versions.. Try to deactivate them.